# My sql:error 1227 ( 42000)

Tags: mysql

I m not able to `create user, create database`, etc. 
I have seen the previous answers to this questions, but the problem still exists. 
Even when i write

```
mysql -h user root -p
```

it gives error.

Please help me.

Comment: Check user privileges `SHOW GRANTS;` [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the user does not have privileges to perform those operation. You need to grant the privileges to that user. Use `SHOW PRIVILEGES`  as swapnesh said to see a list of operations user can perform. To grant privileges you can use this:-

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

More specifically you can use this:-

```
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@hostname identified by 'mypasswd';
```